# Categorical "Grids" in R

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, iteration, data-manipulation

I am working with the R programming language. Suppose I have the following data:

```
library("dplyr")

df <- data.frame(b = rnorm(100,5,5), d = rnorm(100,2,2),
                 c = rnorm(100,10,10))

a <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
a <- sample(a, 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1))

a<- as.factor(a)
df$a = a

> head(df)
           b          d          c a
1  3.1316480  0.5032860  4.7362991 a
2  4.3111450 -0.1142736 -0.5841322 c
3  2.8291346  3.6107839 16.0684492 a
4 14.2142245  4.9893987 -1.8145138 a
5 -6.7381302  0.0416782 -7.7675387 c
6  0.4481874  0.3370716 17.4260801 a
```

I also have the following function ("my_subset_mean") which evaluates the mean of the "column c" given a specific choice of inputs:

```
my_subset_mean <- function(r1, r2, r3){  
  subset <- df %>% filter(a %in% r1, b > r2, d < r3)
  return(mean(subset$c))
}

my_subset_mean(r1 = c("a", "b"), r2 = 5, r3 = 1 ) 
[1] 5.682513
```

**My Question:** I am trying to evaluate the function "my_subset_mean" at random combinations of "r1", "r2" and "r3". For example:

```
 my_subset_mean(r1 = c("a", "b"), r2 = 5, r3 = 1 ) 
[1] 11.46365

 my_subset_mean(r1 = c("a", "b"), r2 = 5, r3 = 1 ) 
[1] 11.46365

 my_subset_mean(r1 = c("a"), r2 = 2, r3 = 0 ) 
[1] 14.59809

my_subset_mean(r1 = c("a", "b", "c"), r2 = 3.1, r3 = 0 ) 
[1] 11.26508

 #I am not sure how to get this one to work (i.e. ignore "r1" all together and only calculate the mean using r2 and r3)

 my_subset_mean(r1 = "NA", r2 = 3.1, r3 = 0 ) 
[1] NaN

etc.
```

Is it possible to make a "grid" that contains random values of "r2" and "r3" (e.g. random values of "r2" and "r3" between 0 and 5) along with random subsets of "r1" (e.g. "a", "c, d", "b, a, e", "d"):

```
> head(my_grid)
           r2          r3   r1
1  3.1316480  0.5032860     a, b
2  4.3111450 -0.1142736     c, d, e
3  2.8291346  3.6107839     a
4 14.2142245  4.9893987     b, e
5 -6.7381302  0.0416782     NA
6  0.4481874  0.3370716     e
```

And then evaluate "my_subset_mean" at each row of "my_grid"? E.g.

```
#desired result

 > head(final_answer)
               r2          r3   r1         my_subset_mean
    1  3.1316480  0.5032860     a, b         0.3
    2  4.3111450 -0.1142736     c, d, e      0.1
    3  2.8291346  3.6107839     a            0.55
    4 14.2142245  4.9893987     b, e         0.6
    5 -6.7381302  0.0416782     NA           0.51
    6  0.4481874  0.3370716     e            0.16
```

If there were no "factor variables" involved, I think I could have done this with an iterative "for loop". But I am not sure how to "feed" the function ("my_subset_mean") using "my_grid". Can someone please show me how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: @ Akrun: thank you for your reply! if there are 5 elements, e.g. c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), then r1 can take any combination of these, 0 elements to 5 elements

Comment: @ Akrun : thank you for your reply! I agree that there can be many combinations that can suddenly get out of control. This why I just wanted to try randomly evaluate this function at a few points (e.g. my_grid with 100 rows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may write a function to select random value for `r1`, `r2` and `r3` based on the data that you have. `runif` will help you create random number in range.

```
create_output <- function() {
  uv <- levels(df$a)
  r1 <- sample(uv, sample(length(uv)))
  rgb <- range(df$b)
  rgd <- range(df$d)
  r2 <- runif(1, rgb[1], rgb[2])
  r3 <- runif(1, rgd[1], rgd[2])
  my_subset_mean <- my_subset_mean(r1, r2, r3)
  data.frame(r1 = toString(r1), r2, r3, my_subset_mean)
}
```

Run it once

```
create_output()

#          r1         r2         r3 my_subset_mean
#1 d, c, e, a -0.5762248 -0.3233672      0.3470009
```

Run it 100 times and bind the result.

```
out <- do.call(rbind, replicate(100, create_output(), simplify = FALSE))
head(out)

#             r1        r2         r3 my_subset_mean
#1          e, d -6.870120  4.9283288      12.604477
#2    d, c, b, e 13.730295  4.0619485       7.749107
#3             e -4.990023  5.4652763      13.441422
#4          c, a  2.095414  5.4337308      10.603865
#5    d, c, b, e -6.614294 -0.4182057       6.703294
#6 a, c, d, b, e 17.369292  3.9566795       7.749107
```

Comment: @ Ronak Shah: Thank you for your answer! Is it possible to make it so that "r1" can sometimes be ignored? I.e. my_subset_mean is only calculated using r2 and r3? thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I think this code might help you

```
library(tidyverse)

r1_sim <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
r2_sim <- seq(0,1,.2)
r3_sim <- seq(0,1,.2)

expand_grid(r1 = r1_sim,r2 = r2_sim, r3 = r3_sim) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(my_subset_mean(r1,r2,r3))

# A tibble: 180 x 4
# Rowwise: 
   r1       r2    r3 `my_subset_mean(r1, r2, r3)`
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>                        <dbl>
 1 a       0     0                           16.5
 2 a       0     0.2                         12.9
 3 a       0     0.4                         12.9
 4 a       0     0.6                         12.9
 5 a       0     0.8                         12.9
 6 a       0     1                           13.4
 7 a       0.2   0                           16.5
 8 a       0.2   0.2                         12.9
 9 a       0.2   0.4                         12.9
10 a       0.2   0.6                         12.9
# ... with 170 more rows
```